# NSIS installer vs Windows 10 Defender - block and message about Trojan Win32/Sprisky.U!cl

Tags: windows-10, nsis, trojan, windows-defender

I created a simple installer in NSIS. During installation, the maxscript files are copied into the corresponding folders of 3ds max and keys are created in the registry for uninstall. The installer works fine in Windows 7, but when i try to run it in Windows 10, the installer is blocked and a warning message appears about the trojan (see image) > [**Win32/Sprisky.U!cl**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd3LJ.jpg)
On my computer this is not a problem for me, I know that there are no viruses and trojans and just continue the installation, canceling any Windows Defender actions. But for other users this is a problem and they are afraid to continue the installation. Why does Windows Defender consider that the NSIS installer is a trojan or a virus ?? How can you get around this and what should be written in the installer script code so that WIndows Defender shut up?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @idleberg Who is this so "smart" who puts a "minus" to all posts? Answer me exactly what I violated the rules in my question, described in the link that you post here?

Comment: As of 2020-12-21 it is registering a false positive on some installers for "Trojan:Win32/Spursint.F!cl", so this seems to be an evolving problem. I assume they'll sort it out soon enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no code changes you can make to remove the warnings. NSIS produces an application that extracts compressed files and executes interpreted code on the fly and this sometimes triggers false positives in antivirus software.

Your only option is to [report the false positive](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_False_Positives#Where_to_report_false_positives) to the antivirus vendor.

Comment: (The NSIS wiki is down right now because Sourceforge is moving servers, you can view the archived version @ https://web.archive.org/web/20170707020952/http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_False_Positives#Where_to_report_false_positives)